# Display another field as 'Node author' if node posted anonymously

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

Currently on my D6 site registered as well as anonymous users can post articles. A custom text field has to be filled by unregistered users while creating an article. This text field's value is shown as Node author for anonymous posters.

Now I am all set to upgrade this site to D7. I tried using the following snippet to display custom text field value as the 'node author' if posted by Anonymous user, But it has some issues...

1. menu_get_object() works only for full node view and not for teasers etc.
2. It also changes $name every where on the page eg: for unregistered comments too.

```
function mytheme_username_alter(&$name, $account) {
  $node = menu_get_object();
    if($account->uid == "0") {
      $name = $node->field_custom_author['und'][0]['value'];
     }
}
```

**Question:** How can I tweak this function to display custom text field's value as 'Node Author' if the node is created by an anonymous user, without changing $name elsewhere on the page?

If there's a better function/solution than this, i am all open to try that too.

Answer (score 1):

You have two viable options:

1. In theme system, use either [node.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7) file to do it, or probably better [`template_preprocess_node(&$variables)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7). I'll discuss function as that's what I prefer. When using function, copy it to your own template.php, renaming to `mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables)`. As a source, use parent theme if it implements it. If not, or if there is no parent theme, use link I provided above.

   Then find a line like this:

   ```
   $variables['node'] = $variables['elements']['#node'];
   ```

   and after it modify `$variables['node']` as you see fit.
2. Use [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) to create a field that shows author's name, and in case of anonymous authors displays arbitrary text. Turn off displaying author and use this field instead.